# TypeError: this.state.student.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So I am trying to load data from an API, but have been getting many problems along the way. I read pretty much everything but to no avail. If there is a better way to structure my code please leave a comment. All help is welcomed.

```
import React, { componentDidMount, Component } from 'react';

class Students extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            student: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ student: data }));
    }

    render() {
        const students = this.state.student.map(pupil => (
            <div key={pupil.id}>
                <p>{pupil.firstName + ` ` + pupil.lastName}</p>
            </div>
        ))
        return (
            <>
                <section className="hero is-fullheight">
                    <div className="hero-body">
                        <div className="container">
                            {students}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Students;
```

I would like to map the array and load all users from the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're getting is an object, not an array. You can just set students from this object.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students`)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => this.setState({ student: data.students }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid usage of Class component, it create too much overhead for react to handle.
Use functional components and use hooks,

the componentDidMount will change to

```
Useeffect(()=>{
 fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ student: data.students }));
},[])
```

if you are using class component try to change the name
`UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`